# Change of base for partial derivatives

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Consider a set of pairs ${x, y}$ such that for all $x$ and $y$:

$$\psi(x, y) = K$$

Further assume that $\psi$ is differentiable with respect to $x$ and $y$ and increasing in both $x$ and $y$.

Consider a change $x \to x + \Delta x$ and $y \to y + \Delta y$ such that

$$\psi (x, y) = \psi(x + \Delta x, y + \Delta y) = K$$

What assumptions do we need to make about $\psi$ to derive a value for:

$$ \frac{\text{d} \Delta y}{\text{d} \Delta x}$$

My hypothesis is that:

$$ \frac{\text{d} \Delta y}{\text{d} \Delta x} = - \frac{\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \Delta y}(x, y)}{\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \Delta x}(x, y)}$$

But I'd like to derive that more formally.

Comment: Can you make more precise your change of coordinates, and the hypothesis on increasing in both $x$ and $y$?  It's unclear (to me at least) what you mean precisely in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem you need to use first is called the “implicit function theorem”.

To give some heuristics, let us assume that the elements of the level set $L=\{(x,y):\psi(x,y)=K\}$ are near some point $(x_0,y_0)\in L$ described by a $C^1$ curve $\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))$ with, say, $\gamma(t_0)=(x_0,y_0)$ and $\gamma'(t)\ne0$ for all $t$ near $t_0$.

The implicit function theorem implies that, if $\psi$ is $C^1$ and at least one of the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)$ or $\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)$ is nonzero, then such a curve actually exists in a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ (and moreover, you can choose either $\gamma_1(t)=t$ or $\gamma_2(t)=t$, depending on which of the two derivatives is nonzero).

Now we have in particular that $\psi(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))=K$ for all $t$ near $t_0$. Then the derivative of the right-hand side with respect to $t$ is zero, and so must be the derivative of the left-hand side with respect to $t$. But this means that $$\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))\gamma_1'(t)+
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))\gamma_2'(t)=0\text.$$

I think what you are asking for is the quotient
$$\frac{\gamma_2'(t_0)}{\gamma_1'(t_0)}\text.$$
But using the above formula, one obtains (if the denominators are not zero):
$$\frac{\gamma_2'(t)}{\gamma_1'(t)}=-\frac{\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))}{\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))}\text.$$
Inserting the value $t_0$ for $t$, this yields:
$$\frac{\gamma_2'(t_0)}{\gamma_1'(t_0)}=-\frac{\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)}{\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)}\text,$$
which is indeed the formula you were conjecturing.

Comment: And you just used the chain rule to get that dΔy/dΔx = (dΔy/dt) / (dΔx/dt), right?

Comment: Yes; once you *know* that it is a differentiable curve, the chain rule can be applied to get this formula.